# Node.js express redirect to another page

Tags: express

Using Node.js and Express I'm trying to redirect to another page by clicking the button in html.
The simplest way is to use:

server.js

```
  res.writeHead(302, {'Location': 'public/new_page.html'})
  res.end();
```

index.html

```
<script>
  fetch('/new_page', {
    method: 'GET',
    redirect: 'follow'
  }).then(function(res){
   window.location.assign(res.url);
</script>
```

But this method reveal "public" folder and it's not good.

Another method is to send html file:

server.js

```
res.sendFile('goods.html', { root: path.join(__dirname, 'public') });
```

But I can not find information on how to run it in html:

index.html

```
<script>
  fetch('/new_page', {
    method: 'GET',
    redirect: 'follow'
  }).then(function(res){
    DO WHAT TO RUN IT?;
  });
</script>
```

Could you advise me a method how to redirect to the new page without revealing 'public' folder, please?

Comment: Didn't use `routes`  in `Express`?

Comment: The examples I gave are minimised. I followed the rule of StackOverflow  "share the minimum amount of code others need to reproduce your problem (also called a minimum, reproducible example) ". Of course it will not work without routing. And the question not about the server side, but about the HTML side.